# Russian domain name in cyrillic

Tags: dns, idn

For my customer I need name of domain in Cyrillic. It is possible? 
And if is possible - every hosting company can support that?

**Example:**
american export stuff

With google translator (I know that´s not correct but is only as example):
Американский экспорт материал

And I would like to have: www.американскии-экспорт-материал.ru

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! But the domain name would be .рф, not .ru.
Your website would look like:
 www.американскии-экспорт-материал.рф (Cyrillic рф for RF - Russian Federation)